# Tailwind styling not working on production build for NextJS but works on dev

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

My styling for Tailwind is not working the production build made using `npm run build` + `npm run start`.

When I do `npm run dev` the styling works and my page looks like (with purple button):

[image]

When I do `npm run start` after building, my page looks like:

[image]

This is my folder structure:

[image]

This is my tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
/* eslint-env node */
module.exports = {
    content: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
        fontFamily: {
            sans: ['Roboto', 'sans-serif'],
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

This is my postcss.config.js:

```
/* eslint-env node */
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
}
```

This is my global.css file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Also I have added tailwindcss as both a dependency and a devDepenency but it still does not fix it.

Any idea how to make it work on production builds?

Comment: Are you using SCSS for your styles? If so, you will have to compile the css while local (can't compile scss on the live server) and upload the updated CSS file to your live server after.

Comment: I'm not using SCSS, just the default tailwind stuff.  I followed this guide to add tailwind to my NextJS project: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

Comment: I still have the Home.module.css file, is that the issue?

Comment: I guess your tailwind classes exist for the element, but during bundle has lower priority. Please check for the element. If it is the case try https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#selector-strategy.

Comment: How do I check for the element?

Answer (score 1):

I have also ran into this issue, and what I have found tailwindcss gets a lower priority; not sure if you are using other libraries like material ui. In my case, react/emotion gets a higher priority than tailwind.

To fix it, you need configure the `tailwind.config.js` and add the `important` field

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  important: '#app',
}
```

see tailwind docs - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#selector-strategy

Then in your nextjs app, find the `__document.jsx` file, and add the `id` param to the body element

```
<Html lang="en">
    <Head />
    <body id="app">
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
    </body>
</Html>
```

That should do the trick, and will render properly in production build

Comment: Tailwind CSS classes were not compiling. And I had to relaunch development server by typing npm run dev for the Tailwind CSS classes to tak effect. After following above tricks the issue has partially fixed. I added id="app" in the layout.tsx file though. Thanks!